# Two python2.7 rand.shuffle programs that never complete

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python (and programming in general) but need to solve this problem. I am attempting to randomize information in a csv file with different rules (this is not homework, it is for work-work). I've gotten a version of this script working before, so I know the basics are OK. However, with the two current versions, they are never successful. I'll include the relevant bits of code below.

```
    import os
import sys
import random
import csv

# Opens the file supplied in the first argument in the command line.
# Then, sets up each row as its own entity for later randomization
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),sys.argv[1]),'rU') as csvfile:
    orderimport = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab, delimiter=',')
    orderdata = []

    next(orderimport,None)
    for row in orderimport:
        orderdata.append(row)

done = False
attempt = 1
max_i = 0

while not done:
    random.shuffle(orderdata)
    done = True; # maybe

# prints the attempts in hundreds of thousands, as well as the max number of lines completed before starting over (however many rows are in the sheet is the max)

    if attempt % 100000 == 0:
        print attempt,max_i
    for i in range(len(orderdata)-3):

# This is where you supply the rules!
# This is useful if you want to prevent blocks of trials. You can change these values to whatever you need sorted. 
        if (orderdata[i][11]==orderdata[i+1][11] and orderdata[i][11]==orderdata[i+2][11] and orderdata[i][11]==orderdata[i+3][11]) or \
        (orderdata[i][6]==orderdata[i+1][6]):
            if i>max_i:
                max_i = i
            done = False
            break
        else:           
            continue
    attempt += 1
# This is where it will saves the file. Do not change this part! 
# Just supply the full desired filename (with file type) as the second argument when running the script.
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),sys.argv[2]),'wb') as csvfile:
    orderexport = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab, delimiter=',')
    for row in orderdata:
        orderexport.writerow(row)
```

and a slightly different program with just the different parts listed:

```
    if abs(int(orderdata[i][5]) - int(orderdata[i+1][5])) < 2 and abs(int(orderdata[i][6]) - int(orderdata[i+1][6])) < 2:
        if i>max_i:
            max_i = i
        done = False
        break
    else:           
        continue
attempt += 1
```

Both work but just keep going and going and are never successful at finding a random list with those rules. Am I doing something silly, or are they just impossible? Thanks!

Comment: How large is your orderdata list? The more elements you have, the less likely it is that any particular shuffle will meet your "no runs" criteria.

Comment: Note that your input could be more simply accomplished using `orderdata = csvfile.readlines()`[1:].

Comment: Excellent question. They are both between 150-200 lines. I left both scripts going overnight and one got to about 101 lines (IIRC) and the other to the 90s.

Comment: Thank you, holdenweb! That kind of stuff is helpful!

Comment: Run the test with a much smaller number of lines, then keep increasing the number. Either you'll find that run time increases exponentially (or worse!), or there's one particular line that makes the conditions impossible to meet.

Comment: Can you post a sample input file to a site like http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which explores all possible orderings of the rows with pruning and backtracking. In this case we are interested in an ordering where `a[i][2] <> a[i+1][2]` for all `i`.

```
def sols(a,avail,avoid):
  if not avail:
    yield []
  for i in avail:
    r = a[i]
    if not (avoid and r[2] == avoid):   -- to see all orderings, change to "if True:"
      avail1 = avail - set([i])
      for s in sols(a, avail1, r[2]):
        yield [r]+s

def solutions(a):
  inds = range(0, len(a))
  return sols(a, set(inds), None)

arr = [ [1,1,10,1,1], [2,2,30,2,2], [3,3,10,3,3], [4,4,30,4,4] ]
for s in solutions(arr):
  print s
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4]]
[[1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2]]
[[2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3]]
[[2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1]]
[[3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4]]
[[3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2]]
[[4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3]]
[[4, 4, 30, 4, 4], [3, 3, 10, 3, 3], [2, 2, 30, 2, 2], [1, 1, 10, 1, 1]]
```

Note that of the 24 possible permutations of the 4 rows only 8 are printed.
You can verify that it explores all possible permutation by changing the second if statement in sols() to "if True" and you'll get all 24.

To select a random one, just shuffle the input array and take the first solution:

```
random.shuffle(arr)
print "a random ordering:", solutions(arr).next()
```

Note: I think the algorithm can be tweaked to use memory more efficiently - I'll look into that.

*Update:* Here is (I'm sure is) a more efficient solution which uses tuples to share memory.
In this case I've implemented your first exclusion rule.

```
def sols(a,avail,avoid,x1,x2,x3):
  if not avail:
    yield None
  for i in avail:
    r = a[i]
    bad = (avoid and r[6]) or (x1 and x2 and x3 and x1 == x2 and x2 == x3 and x3 == r[11])
    if not bad:
      avail1 = avail - set([i])
      for s in sols(a, avail1, r[6], x2, x3, r[11]):
        yield (r,s)

def fromTuples(t):
  arr = []
  while isinstance(t, tuple):
    arr.append( t[0] )
    t = t[1]
  return arr

def solutions(a):
  for s in sols(a, set(range(len(a))), None, None, None, None):
    yield fromTuples(s)

def randomSolution(a):
  solutions(random.shuffle(a)).next()
```

Your other exclusion rule can be implemented by modifying `sols` as follows:

```
def sols(a, avail, x5, x6):
  ...
    bad = (x5 && abs(x5 - r[5]) < 2) and (x6 && abs(x6 - r[6]) < 2)
    ...
      for s in sols(a, avail1, r[5], r[6]):
        ...
```

Of course, there may not be any permutation which satisfies your exclusion rules, and in that case you will get a StopIteration exception.